# How does primitive recursion handle mutual recursion?

Tags: computability, recursion, primitive-recursion

My intuition is that you can't call a function that has not yet been defined, although I have yet to find a source confirming this.

Is this true?

Thanks, friends :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Suppose you have two mutually recursive maps $f, g : 
\mathbb{N}  \to \mathbb{N}$ defined by
\begin{align*}
f(n) &= \Phi(f, g, n), \\
g(n) &= \Psi(f, g, n)
\end{align*}
We may replace this with a *single* recursive map $h : \mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{N} \times \mathbb{N}$, where $h(n) = (f(n), g(n))$, so that $f(n) = \pi_1(h(n))$, $g(n) = \pi_2(h(n))$. Then the above recursive definition may be rewriten as
$$
h(n) = (\Phi(\pi_1 \circ h, \pi_2 \circ h, n), \Psi(\pi_1 \circ h, \pi_2 \circ h, n)) 
$$
The above trick is very general and works in many situations. Regarding primitive recursion, we just have to verify that the passage between $f, g$ and $h$ preserves the primitive recursive nature of functions, which it does because pairing, projections and compositions are primitive recursive.